# No me toma los estilos de angular/material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material, estilos

Estoy agregando algunos componentes de angular, por ejemplo card pero no me está tomando los estilos propios de ese componente.

material.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PresentationComponent } from './components/presentation/presentation.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PresentationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.html

```
<h1>vehiculo</h1>
<mat-card class='card' *ngFor="let vehiculo of vehiculos_asignados">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Patente:{{vehiculo.patente}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button (click)="openDialog()"mat-button>Más Información</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
  <mat-card-content>
    {{nombre_tecnico}}
    {{vehiculo.marca}}
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Por ejemplo,no me aparece el estilo de sombra del componente card ni tampoco cuando se abre el componente dialogo no me aparece superpuesto ni ese efecto de que está sobre el resto de los componentes como se muestra en la página de angular/material

Comment: Y que sucede cuando utilizas un mat-input o un mat-select, también pasa lo mismo??